# 10.9 server keeps losing correct permissions on /private/tmp

Tags: macos, osx-server, permission

about 2-3 a week our 10.9 server machine starts filling logs with 'unable to write to /private/tmp/..." errors.  many per second.  the permissions to go 755 apparently.

it's easily fixed with a manual setting of permissions or a disk util repairpermissions.  but if uncaught, it causes problems for the server (of course).  nothing obvious in logs just before these errors start.

i can't figure out what's causing this to go wonky repeatedly.  has anyone seen similar behavior?  not sure what's causing it.  nothing suspicious in chron or launchagents/daemons.

i'm using sns iscsi initiator, in case anyone else out there has seen this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe resetting the permissions on a user's home directory helps: 
This is easily accomplished by resetting ACLs on the desired home directly by using the Reset Password Utility in the Recovery Partition:
    1   Restart your computer from the recovery partition (restart while holding **CMD+R**). 
    2   Open Disk Utility and run a permissions repair on your startup volume. After this is complete, close Disk Utility (doing this just for good measure).
    3   Open Terminal from the Utilities menu. Type in *resetpassword* and select your user account (NOT System Administrator/root) from the drop down menu. 
    4   Click the Reset Button at the bottom of the window in the Reset home folder permissions and ACLs section. 
    5   Quit the Password Utility and go back to the main recovery screen. 
    6   On your keyboard, hit **CMD+Q** and restart your computer. *It's very important that you don't hold down the power button to exit the recovery session, or the ACL reset won't occur*.

Comment: How will setting permissions on a home director affect /tmp ?